# Python/Numpy: Convert list of bools to unsigned int

Tags: python, list, numpy, scipy

1. What is the fastest (or most "Pythonic") way to convert

   ```
   x = [False, False, True, True]
   ```

   into `12`? (If there is such a way.)
2. What if `x` were instead a `numpy.array` of bools? Is there a special command for that?

I have a large m-by-n array of booleans, where each n-element row represents a single low-dimensional hash of a high-dimensional feature vector. (In the example above, n = 4.) I would like to know the answer in order to compress my data as much as possible. Thank you.

---

*Edit*: Thank you for the responses! Using the following test code,

```
t = 0
for iter in range(500):
    B = scipy.signbit(scipy.randn(1000,20))
    for b in B:
        t0 = time.clock()
        # test code here
        t1 = time.clock()
        t += (t1-t0)
print t
```

...here were the runtimes on my Thinkpad laptop:

- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065737/python-numpy-convert-list-of-bools-to-unsigned-int/4065901#4065901): 4.26 sec
- [Sven Marnach 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065737/python-numpy-convert-list-of-bools-to-unsigned-int/4065778#4065778): 7.88
- [Emil H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065737/python-numpy-convert-list-of-bools-to-unsigned-int/4065774#4065774): 8.51
- [Sven Marnach 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065737/python-numpy-convert-list-of-bools-to-unsigned-int/4065778#4065778): 8.72
- [delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065737/python-numpy-convert-list-of-bools-to-unsigned-int/4065779#4065779): 10.14
- [liori](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065737/python-numpy-convert-list-of-bools-to-unsigned-int/4065807#4065807): 53.49

Of course, I welcome any independent tests that may confirm or refute my data!

---

*Edit*: In my answer below, changing `int(j)` to simply `j` still works, but runs six times as slow! Then perhaps the other answers would become faster if the bool was casted using `int`. But I'm too lazy to test everything again.

---

*Edit*: liori posted results of independent tests [here](http://pastebin.com/x1FEP9gY).

Comment: What's the rule to convert the [False, False, True, True] into 12?

Comment: `x[0]` is the LSB, and `x[-1]` is the MSB.

Comment: Please use `timeit` for testing, it is much less prone to errors. My times: http://pastebin.com/x1FEP9gY

Comment: Thanks for the tests! I don't doubt them at all. I have added them to the post.

Comment: Just something to note - in liori's test, sven2() fails miserably because we are using 1000-bit numbers. Check the results (as in the numbers returned by each function) and you'll see that its result is wrong for that large of a number.

Comment: @Justing Peel - While you're quite correct in general, unless I'm missing something, the example is using 20-bit numbers, _not_ 1000-bit!  There shouldn't be any problem with 20 columns on the numpy-based methods....

Comment: I think he means in the tests that liori posted. The vector length is 1000 and is tested over 1000 trials.

Comment: @Steve - Ah, that makes more sense! Thanks, and sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking various ideas from various other answers, here's another way to do it:

```
sum(1<<i for i, b in enumerate(x) if b)
```

It is quite fast in my tests - right up with the numpy method for large number of bits even though it overflows like crazy. I used liori's testing module for testing. Steve's method, with the change I suggested, is just barely faster. However, if a lot of these sorts of conversions need to be done at a time (and with not too many bits), I'm betting that numpy will be faster.

Comment: `sum(b<<i for i, b in enumerate(x))`

Comment: @KennyTM. Clever but I profiled it the original is about 20% faster. It's the fastest by far.

Answer (score 6):

Most Pythonic might be this:

```
sum(2**i*b for i, b in enumerate(x))
```

It's hard to tell if it is also the fastest.

In numpy I would use

```
numpy.sum(2**numpy.arange(len(x))*x)
```

but this won't be faster for small arrays `x`, and it won't work for big arrays `x` since machine size integers are used instead of Pythons arbitrary precision ints.

Comment: Thanks! For some array sizes, the second solution worked quite well, but for others it didn't.

Comment: @Steve - The other advantage of the numpy solution is that you can avoid iterating through each row.  Using the "`B`" array from your test code above: `numpy.sum(2**numpy.arange(B.shape[1])*B, axis=1)`. This should give a large speedup compared with iterating over each row in the array... The full 500x loop executes in less than a second on my machine...

Comment: Since numpy doesn't handle large integers the same as Python, you have to be careful with really large numbers. If there will larger numbers, you can get a little more out of this method by doing `dtype=numpy.longlong` in arange(). Also, there is a very, very small speed-up by using the sum method of the resultant numpy array rather than using numpy.sum.

Answer (score 3):

```
reduce(lambda a,b:2*a+b, reversed(x))
```

You could get rid of reversed() if you had least significant bit at the end of array. This works with numpy.array too, and doesn't need enumerate(). From my tests seem to be faster too: no need to use exponentiation.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution! I was blown away when I first saw it. Unfortunately, it seems to run the slowest, with or without `reversed`. Might anyone know why?

Comment: @Steve: on my computer it is faster than sum+exponentiation. Funny thing... how long vectors do you use? Do you test performance using `timeit`?

Answer (score 2):

An elegant, pythonic, always-working way is this:

```
def powers(x):
    """yield powers of x, starting from x**0 forever"""
    power = 1
    while True:
        yield power
        power *= x

def bools_to_int(bools):
    # in Python 2, use itertools.izip!
    return sum(int(place) * place_weight for place_weight, place in 
               zip(powers(2), bools))
```

Note that you *can* get rid of `powers` (by enumerate and squaring in the comprehension, as other answers do) - but maybe it's clearer this way.

Comment: Your answer doesn't give the same answer as the others. Substituting `bools` for `reversed(bools)` fixes it.

Comment: @Justin Peel: Come again? I already noticed that shortly after answering and added `reversed`...

Comment: try the code that you have here with the example given by the OP. I get 3 as the answer when it should be 12. You didn't need to put the `reversed` in.

Comment: *bashes head against wall* @Justin: Yes, you're right and now I realize why.

Answer (score 2):

My initial attempt, just for reference:

```
def bool2int(x):
    y = 0
    for i,j in enumerate(x):
        if j: y += int(j)<<i
    return y
```

Comment: Wait, this is interesting: changing `int(j)` to simply `j` still works, but runs six times as slow!

Comment: If you just change `int(j)` to 1, yours is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
>>> x = [False, False, True, True]
>>> sum([int(y[1])*2**y[0] for y in enumerate(x)])
12
```

You can convert a numpy array to a regular list using a `list()` cast.

```
>>> a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> list(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: `0**0` is 1, so you get an off-by-one error if the first element is False.

Comment: @liori, I don't believe that applies to my code, since I don't actually do that anywhere? Still interesting, though. Didn't know that.

Comment: `int(False)*2==0`. First index given by `enumerate` is `0`.

Comment: @liori, Yes, but I don't raise the value of that to any power. My code does i * 2^j. For the first bit that is i * 2^0 = i*1 = i

Comment: Ok, shame on me. I messed up precedence rules :-).

Comment: @liori, No problem. In the end, your solution was more elegant anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a matrix, you probably want to do it like this:

```
#precompute powers of two
vals = 2.**np.arange(20)

B = ....
compressed = np.dot(B, vals) # matrix multiplication.
```

np.dot should be faster than any loop in Python. Much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying `ipython %timeit` and it seems that doing the following is faster:

```
y = 0
for i,j in enumerate(x):
    if j: y += 1<<i
```

In addition, if your boolean vector is a numpy.ndarray, converting it to python array `x.tolist()` and running the same seems to work faster in this case. It's all marginal, but consistent as well as, at these speeds, marginals add up well.

Answer (score 1):

numpy has the [packbits](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) function for this.
It also supports operations along axes:

```
In [3]: B = scipy.signbit(scipy.randn(1000,8)).astype("i1")

In [3]: B[0]
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int8)

In [4]: np.packbits(B[0])
Out[4]: array([68], dtype=uint8)

In [5]: %timeit np.packbits(B, axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 37 µs per loop
```

it works for int8 sizes for larger sizes you have to shift and or

```
In [8]: x # multiple of 8
Out[8]: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int8)

In [9]: r = np.packbits(x).astype(np.int32); r
Out[9]: array([171, 129], dtype=uint8)

In [10]: r[0] << 8 | r[1] 
Out[10]: 33237

In [11]: sum(1<<i for i, b in enumerate(x[::-1]) if b)
Out[11]: 33237
```

if `x` is no multiple of 8 you have to pad in zeros

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to add another extension to the mix, I added pack() and unpack() to the development branch of gmpy. My tests show it may be 2x or 3x faster.

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.pack([0,0,1,1],1)
mpz(12)
>>> gmpy2.unpack(12,1)
[mpz(0), mpz(0), mpz(1), mpz(1)]
```

Disclaimer: The development version is called gmpy2 and can co-exist with the stable version. It is still in alpha phase but will hopefully become beta in a few weeks. You need to have both GMP and MPFR libraries installed. The source is available at http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/checkout