# How to convert stack of rows of binary digits into column of values in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, binary, number-systems

Suppose I have

```
>>> np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

This is a matrix, each of lines of which can be regarded as binary representation of some number, so it is

```
>>> np.array([[0],[1],[2],[3]])
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

How to calculate this transformation in shortest way in Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Please provide some samples of what you have attempted and we would be happy to help you narrow in on an optimal solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505514/binary-numpy-array-to-list-of-integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matrix-multiplication` with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) to do element-wise scaling of each column with appropriate 2-powered numbers and then sum-reduce each row, leading us to few approaches -

```
a.dot(2**np.arange(a.shape[1]-1,-1,-1))
a[:,::-1].dot(2**np.arange(a.shape[1]))
a.dot(1 << np.arange(a.shape[1])[::-1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [557]: a = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])

In [558]: a.dot(2**np.arange(a.shape[1]-1,-1,-1))
Out[558]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [559]: a[:,::-1].dot(2**np.arange(a.shape[1]))
Out[559]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [566]: a.dot(1 << np.arange(a.shape[1])[::-1])
Out[566]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Will read it for a week :)

Comment: Can also use `np.packbits` and `np.right_shift`.  As a matter of fact I think I'll add that to the answers in the non-dupe question.