# Converting Binary Numpy Array into Unsigned Integer

Tags: python, numpy

I have a long 2D matrix of Numpy array object whose dimension is n x 12. Here is the first 10 rows of this matrix:

```
b = ([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

What I want to do with this array is to convert it to unsigned integer. As far as I know the fastest way to do it is by using `np.packbits` function. However this function only packs 8 bits into integer while my array above has 12 bits in each row. What I expect when converting array above to unsigned integer are:

```
250, 248, 248, 250, 248, 248, 248, 248, 248, 248
```

Does any one know how get above result ? I also tried by `np.packbits` above by extending the bits to 16 (`.view('u2'), the result is still not as I expected. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are the first 4 columns always going to be full of zeros?

Comment: No, they aren't, example above is only the first 10 rows. So in some rows, they are filled with 1 or 0. The result I got above is by using Matlab command bi2de

Comment: So, you would need `uint16` to store the output values, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary numpy array to list of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505514/binary-numpy-array-to-list-of-integers)

Comment: @Divakar: It doesn't have to be in 'uint16', what I want to have is they are fit in 12 bits.

Comment: @Busy Beaver, probably not, the example you mentioned is 8 bits or less than 8 bits array converted to integers which seems no issue when using 'np.packbits' function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could slice out the first `4` columns and last `8` columns and use [`np.packbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) separately on those. Then, scale the first slice to account for them being the most-significant *block* among them and add with the second slice.

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
slice0 = np.packbits(b[:,:-8], axis=-1).astype(np.uint16) * 16
slice1 = np.packbits(b[:,-8:], axis=-1).astype(np.uint16)
out = slice0 + slice1
```

Alternatively, using `sum-redcution` with `matrix-multiplication` -

```
b.dot(2**np.arange(b.shape[1]-1,-1,-1))
```

Sample run -

```
In [1045]: b
Out[1045]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)

In [1046]: slice0 = np.packbits(b[:,:-8], axis=-1).astype(np.uint16) * 16
      ...: slice1 = np.packbits(b[:,-8:], axis=-1).astype(np.uint16)
      ...: out = slice0 + slice1
      ...: 

In [1047]: out.ravel()
Out[1047]: array([1786,  248,  248,  250,  248,  248,  248,  248, 1272,  760])

In [1048]: b.dot(2**np.arange(b.shape[1]-1,-1,-1))
Out[1048]: array([1786,  248,  248,  250,  248,  248,  248,  248, 1272,  760])
```

Comment: Result is still  not the same as I shown in my question  above, I expect to get these unsigned integer number  '250, 248, 248, 250, 248, 248, 248, 248, 248, 248'.

Comment: @Javen Well I added variety there by adding two 1s in row1 and one 1 in last row for `b`. So, my `b` is different and hence that different output.

Comment: yes it works like a charm, but I need to reverse first each row to MSB-LSB. I prefer to use code In [1048], it works pretty fast. One more thing, I did some mistakes, the array above should be 11 bits not 12 bits as I put it in my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution to the problem would be

```
from numpy import *
b = ([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

def bin2int(x):
    y = 0
    for i,j in enumerate(x):
        y += j<<i
    return y


result = [bin2int(x[::-1]) for x in b]
```

so you don't have to worry about how many bits anymore.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Yes, it works too  but I need to reverse bit in each row so the order will be MSB-LSB. The bits I show in my question supposed to 11 bits, not 12 bits. With this 11 bits, it would produce the same result as I put in my question.