# How to change a binary numpy array into an int?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binary

I have task of converting an array with binary numbers into a decimal number.
My array code looks like this:

```
koo = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
print(koo)
```

Example of the output is:

```
[1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
```

And what I'm supposed to do is to turn it into a string (1010000010), in order to then turn it into a decimal number (642). What could be a way to do this?

For this task I have to create it with the array, I cannot use np.binary_repr()

I have tried solving it with the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505514/binary-numpy-array-to-list-of-integers), but when working on it the numbers would be wildly different from what's true (i.e.: 1011111010 was 381 according to the program, while in reality it's 762)

Anybody knows how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try ```koo.dot(1 << np.arange(koo.size)[::-1])```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, convert Numpy array to string by simply appending elements.
Then, using [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), recast the string using base of 2.

```
koo = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
print(koo)
binaryString = ""
for digit in koo:
    binaryString += str(digit)
print(binaryString)
decimalString = int(binaryString, base=2)
print(decimalString)
```

An example run:

```
[0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
0010100000
160
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list comprehension to enumerate the digits from end to beginning and then calculate the numbers in base ten, then sum. for example:

`np.sum([digit * 2 ** i for i, digit in enumerate(koo[::-1])])`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> koo = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
>>> koo
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

>>> binary_string =  ''.join(koo.astype('str').tolist())
>>> binary_string
'1100001111'

>>> binary_val = int('1100001111', 2)
>>> binary_val
783
```

Comment: You don't need `.tolist()`. `str.join()` will happily use any iterable, which a numpy array is one.